# JNI application throw NoSuchMethodError. Cannot find sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass and prefetchRead

Tags: jvm, java-native-interface

For JNI binding, I had built a c++ application with cmake. Then after I ran the test, It reported an error.

The code is as below,

//Java code with native method:

```java
public class CimFileHelper {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CimFileHelper");
    }

    public native CimElement[] load(String filePath) throws IOException;
}
```

// C++ Implementation. Binding to java method: CimFileHelper.load

```c
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_xxx_CimFileHelper_load
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring file_path) {
    // call load_cim_file
}

// load xml.
int load_cim_file(JNIEnv *env, const char* file_path, jobject (*cim_elem_list)[]) {
    // call load_elements
}

// load children elements.
int load_elements(JNIEnv *env, xml_node root, jobject (*list)[]) {
    int count = 0;
    for (xml_node node = root.first_child(); node; node=node.next_sibling()) {
        if (node.type() != node_element) continue;

        jobject cim_elem = load_element(env, node);
        (*list)[count++] = cim_elem;
        env->DeleteLocalRef(cim_elem);
        if (count>3) break; // make a short test.
    }

    return count;
}

// load each element
jobject load_element(JNIEnv *env, xml_node node) {
    jobject cim_elem = new_instance(env, CLS_NAME_CIM_ELEMENT);

    const char_t* node_tag_w = node.name();
    string node_tag = as_utf8(node_tag_w);
    set_str_value(env, cim_elem, CLS_NAME_CIM_ELEMENT, FIELD_NAME_CIM_ELEMENT_TYPE, node_tag.c_str());

    string text = get_element_text(node);
    if (!text.empty()) 
        set_str_value(env, cim_elem, CLS_NAME_CIM_ELEMENT, FIELD_NAME_CIM_ELEMENT_TEXT, text.c_str());

    return cim_elem;
}

// java new instance.
jobject new_instance(JNIEnv *env, const char* class_name) {
    jclass cls = find_class(env, class_name);

    jmethodID constructor = find_method(env, class_name, METHOD_NAME_CONSTRUCTOR, SIG_METHOD_EMPTY_VOID);
    if (!constructor) {
        cerr<<"Cannot find construtor for "<<class_name<<endl;
        throw ERR_METHOD_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    
    jobject obj = env->NewObjectA(cls, constructor, new jvalue[0]);

    return obj;
}
```

Then run a test case on CimFileHelper.load, It would interrupted with a report as below:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f2f7339061f, pid=82817, tid=0x00007f2fc52ac700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_352-b08) (build 1.8.0_352-352-b08)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.352-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libCimFileHelper.so+0x4961f]  load_elements(JNIEnv_*, pugi::xml_node, _jobject* (*) [])+0x11f

...

Stack: [0x00007f2fc51ad000,0x00007f2fc52ad000],  sp=0x00007f2fc52ab670,  free space=1017k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libCimFileHelper.so+0x4961f]  load_elements(JNIEnv_*, pugi::xml_node, _jobject* (*) [])+0x11f
C  [libCimFileHelper.so+0x4983c]  load_cim_file(JNIEnv_*, char const*, _jobject* (*) [])+0x1c2
C  [libCimFileHelper.so+0x1a982]  Java_com_xxx_CimFileHelper_load+0x4e
j  com.xxx.CimFileHelper.load(Ljava/lang/String;)[Lcom/xxx/CimElement;+0
j  com.xxx.CimFileHelperTest.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+59
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x65600e]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0xf3e
V  [libjvm.so+0x6b750a]  jni_invoke_static(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*) [clone .isra.195]+0x30a
V  [libjvm.so+0x6c905e]  jni_CallStaticVoidMethod+0x16e
C  [libjli.so+0x82b9]  JavaMain+0xa09
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x8ea7]  start_thread+0xd7

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.xxx.CimFileHelper.load(Ljava/lang/String;)[Lcom/xxx/CimElement;+0
j  com.xxx.CimFileHelperTest.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+59
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

...

Internal exceptions (6 events):
Event: 0.018 Thread 0x00007f2fc000a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x000000076d307cd8) thrown at [/home/centos/8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 4014]
Event: 0.018 Thread 0x00007f2fc000a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x000000076d307fc0) thrown at [/home/centos/8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 4014]
Event: 1.439 Thread 0x00007f2f78001000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076dd97d00) thrown at [/home/centos/8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1514]
Event: 1.439 Thread 0x00007f2f78001000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076dd980f8) thrown at [/home/centos/8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1514]
Event: 1.440 Thread 0x00007f2f78001000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076dd9af18) thrown at [/home/centos/8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1514]
Event: 1.440 Thread 0x00007f2f78001000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076dd9b310) thrown at [/home/centos/8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1514]

...
```

I have spent few days on this issue. Any idea would be grateful.

Comment: That’s the price for calling internal methods; they can change at any time. This method (overload) existed in Java 7, but doesn’t in Java 8. Only the method having `ClassLoader` and `ProtectionDomain` in addition to the other parameters exist in Java 8. But note that starting with Java 11, there will be no `defineClass` method in `sun.misc.Unsafe` at all.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `Unsafe` /`prefetchRead`. There is a bug in your JNI code. Try running with `-Xcheck:jni` and don't forget to check return values of all JNI functions.

Comment: I agree. While it’s likely that the code doesn’t do the intended things due to the absent methods, the crash is not caused by that. To me, the most suspicious statement is `(*list)[count++] = cim_elem;` as it blindly trusts a caller provided storage. And if it didn’t crash at this point already, one may wonder what the caller will do with those references, as `DeleteLocalRef` has been called already for each of them. The remaining question is, “*Why implement a task like* ‘iterate over XML elements, create a (Java) object for each, and return a (Java) array of them’ *in `native` code?*”